# Como saber em qual parte do código uma excessão aconteceu olhando a Saída do Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Percebi que em algumas requisições a saída do meu *Visual Studio* exibe algumas mensagens como por exemplo essa:

> Exceção gerada: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' em mscorlib.dll
>
> Exceção gerada: 'System.NullReferenceException' em SiteTeste.dll

Segue o *PrintScreen* dos erros na saída

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algumas *exceptions* são exibidas a *classe/linha* que o erro aconteceu, porém olhando essas eu fico no escuro. Como posso saber em qual parte do sistema esses erros estão acontecendo?

Comment: Existe um atributo na Exception chamado StackTrace, ele mostra onde o erro ocorreu e as propagações dele

Comment: @GuilhermeBarros mas essas exceptions estão acontecendo e o programa não está parando(como quando acontece uma exception), ele pula a Exception sabe? só loga na saída e mais nd...

Comment: Cara, nas actions é interessante cobrir as ações com try catch e, ai, capturar as exceções e, como você quer exibir o StackTrace das exceções no console, você usará o Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) e Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace) e depois dará um throw novamente

Answer (score 0):

Abrindo a janela Exception Settings (atalho ctrl+alt+e) dá uma olhada se a exceção em questão está selecionada (tem um pesquisar ali que facilita), se não estiver selecionada é só selecionar que quando cair na exceção ele para

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]